# Java JTable Custom Design

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am creating a desktop application in Java to take away from manual tasks that we currently implement using word documents. As you can imagine this is slow, leaves room for error etc.

The word document captures data in a form, we then manually add this to a spreadsheet and print off the form. The java application will use a local derby database for storing the captured database, and will allow creation of the old windows document on the fly for legacy reasons (I will create this by writing the raw xml into the docx format).

My problem is creating a data capture form in Java. Sure I can do it using the standard components as standalone and then just get the values from the jTextField areas on form submission, but I find I cant line them up or make them look slick enough. The current MSWord form uses a simple table but has merged fields for headings every few rows to clearly mark different parts of the form. Can this be done using a `JTable`? Also in the column values on certain rows I would liek a normal text entry, but on others radio buttons or a combo box. Can this be done on a row by row basis for each column? From what I can tell this makes a change to the entire column (all rows).

I have been looking at `TableModels`, `TableColumnModels` and so on, if someone could point me in the right direction, or at a tutorial for advanced form creation that would be great.

Or is a `JTable` not the right component for this? Am I missing something?

**Edit:** Current form looks something like this:

```
[ One long cell across the two columns]

    [ name:] [value]

  [ address] [value]

   [ gender] [value]

[one long cell across the two columns for part 2 heading]

[ interests] [combo box ]

...

...
```

and so on (the long merged cells i think is going to be the trickiest?).

Look forward to the responses, many thanks!

Comment: For DocX, you can always have a look at [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j). For the Swing part, I am not completely sure to understand properly your requirements, but it sounds to me that `JTable` is not what you are looking for. I would rather use a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout` or a `MigLayout` as the LayoutManager. Then, all you need is to set up the different form fields.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a *form*. Check out [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/).